# How to make a react component with an image that can be "turned off" when placed in other components?

Tags: reactjs

First React project here, so probably a very elementary question, but I'd appreciate any help as I'm not really sure how to phrase my question to search.  I have this component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import SmallOgLogo from '../../../static/images/OG_logo.jpg';

export default class HeaderNavbar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        showImage: true
      }
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='header-navbar'>
          <div>
            <img className='SmallOgLogo' src={SmallOgLogo}/>
          </div>
        )}
          <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is a header for a project I'm working on. It is on every page in the React project. However, on the "title page" (first page users see with the option to "register" or "login"), I don't want it to display SmallOgLogo. On every other page, it will (hence the default setting of true. How can I make it so when I embed this component in another component, I can do something like ? Can anyone clarify? Thank you!

Comment: tried using conditional rendering? (i.e) ternary operator??

Comment: Just need a conditional render, e.g. `{this.state.showImage ? <img className='SmallOgLogo' src={SmallOgLogo}/> : null}`

Comment: Thanks, yes a ternary operator crossed my mind. My question (which doesn't seem to display in my original question for some reason...) is more about when I put this HeaderNavbar component into another component, how can I affect the state of HeaderNavbar from the other component? To clarify, if I have a "titlePage" component with "HeaderNavbar" inside, how can I set HeaderNavbar's state.showImage to false?  I would assume I somehow pass it as a prop to other components, but not sure how to do that? I hope that helps clarify and thanks for taking the time to answer!